# Losing buildContext after sign-out of Flutter Firebase app

Tags: firebase, flutter, provider

I am able to login with my Flutter Firebase App first time, after I sign Out and login again, I am getting provider out of context error and the app comes back to login screen. When I login again, I am able to login successfully. I believe I am losing the build Context after signing out of Flutter Firebase app.

All my providers are above Material App, the home of material app is login screen.
Screenshot of my widget inspector before sign: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sznk0.png
After successful sign-in the widget inspector is as follows: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2omkU.png
Screenshot of my widget inspector after successful sign-Out:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUHjm.png

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your Provider scope at the root level. I don't know what is inside your provider scope because I did not see your code but it should be something like this.

```
return Provider<int>.value(
  value: value,
  child: MyApp(),
);
```

I suggest you look into [Riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod) because it can be done in a much cleaner way without having to mention all of these different providers. Like this:

```
return ProviderScope(
  child: MyApp(),
);
```

Comment: All my providers are above MaterialApp.

Comment: Can you share the error please?

Comment: E/flutter ( 7829): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
E/flutter ( 7829): #0      Element.widget
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3156
E/flutter ( 7829): #1      Provider._inheritedElementOf
package:provider/src/provider.dart:341
E/flutter ( 7829): #2      Provider.of
package:provider/src/provider.dart:293
E/flutter ( 7829): #3      _SignInState.build.<anonymous closure>
package:pos/…/authenticate/sign_in.dart:200
E/flutter ( 7829): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7829):

Comment: This is the code which is giving Null check error, due to context not available:                               Provider.of<NotificationService>(context,
                                        listen: false)
                                    .changeLoggedInUserId(loggedInUserId);

Comment: The NotificationService is a ChangeNotifier and its ChangeNotifierProvider  is defined above MaterialApp.

Answer (score 0):

still facing the issue.  The consumer provider did not solve the problem.